# Best way to set the currentUserID Using Firebase Auth and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, xcode8

I am building an app using Firebase. I would like to know which is the best way to set a current user session with Swift and Firebase. Should I make a User Object and assign the ID to that object as an attribute and then set it nil when the user logs out? Or is there a simpler way sharing that currentUserID across view controllers?

Comment: Can you be more clear, Do you just wanna access current user UID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase comes with solution to this:

```
let userID: String = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
print(userID)
```

Just found out.